# Detect serial break linux

Tags: linux, uart

Is it possible to detect a serial breaks and tell which serial port generated it on Linux? I've seen some solutions that generates a sigint from breaks, but I need to know which one of 2 serial ports reads the break which as far as i understand it can't be done with the sigints.

Comment: How do you get a sigint on a *framing error*?  I'm aware of the `BRKINT` termios input mode flag, which generates a sigint on a BREAK.  A RS-232 BREAK is a specific kind of framing error, caused by holding the line at space level for more than some length of time, usually one character time.  So it's like an all zero data word with a framing error.  But a framing error on a non-all zero data word isn't a BREAK.  How do you get a signal on that?

Comment: my bad, you don't get it from the framing error, but rather the break (which causes a framing error as it doesn't have a start bit). I'll update the question

Comment: IMO you'd be better off simply configuring termios to report the break condition in the received data (e.g. as three data bytes `0xFF, 0x00, 0x00`), rather than generate a signal.  Use this 3-byte pattern as the message delimiter in your lexical scan for messages (i.e. don't rely of the read() syscall to provide you with aligned and complete message packets).

Comment: Trying to use a signal when the break is intended to delimit messages is likely to fail.  It means that you're taking an "event" in the data stream, and instead trying to use it in the time domain of your executing program.  But since data received by a UART is buffered multiple times in Linux, this latency in "reading" the data in userspace means that the signal is poorly synchronized with data from a **read()** syscall.

Comment: You've asked an XY question, as demonstrated by your exchange of comments with TrentP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BRKINT` will send a signal if the serial port is the controlling tty of the foreground process group.  A session can have **at most one** controlling tty.  So I don't think you need to worry about telling which port the signal is from as you can't get signals from more than one port to begin with.

This `termios` stuff is ancient UNIX for the days when everyone connected to a multi-user mainframe with serial teletype terminals.  Software archaeology.  It wasn't meant for monitoring serial UARTs, rather so random UNIX commands that didn't know anything about serial ports could automatically exit when someone's modem hung up.  `vi` could save the file you were editing.  Hitting the 'BREAK' key on your vt102 terminal would cause the current command to exit.

If you want to use this, I think you'll have to have two process, each one monitoring a single serial port.  You'll know which port got the break based on which one got the signal.  You'll have to make each process its own session leader (see `setsid()`) and set the serial port to the controlling tty (see `TIOCSCTTY` and `TIOCSPGRP`).

Another method is to continuously poll the serial ports using the `TIOCGICOUNT` ioctl.  This will give you counters for the number of break, frame, and parity errors on that port.  Watch for them to increase.  Of course polling is much less efficient than getting a signal and means it may take up to your polling interval before discovering the break.

I'm not sure what your application is, but I've found trying to talk ancient and obscure RS-232 protocols with stock Linux to be problematic.  Things like monitoring a bank of serial lines for BREAKs, or using a 10 μs gap between characters to signal inter-packet framing, or characters greater than 8 bits wide, etc. just don't work well.  If you can do kernel programming, you can create a custom line discipline that makes these things possible.  One could have a break (or framing error, or parity error) monitoring line discipline where all you have to do is call `select()` from userspace on your port(s)  and it will signal when the monitored event occurs.

Comment: I want to be able to read DMX512 (stage lighting protocol), so I basically want to treat any error as a message to start over on a new set of data. One idea came to me that i could use a timout on reading from the serial port instead of actually getting a signal from a brak/other error. are there any big risks with doing that? i should have at least 1ms between the sets of data

Comment: Sounds like I was right about the ancient protocol thing.  Are you sure it generates BREAKs to signal a new set of data?  A break is a >1 character at `space` level.  RS-232 is idle at `mark` level.  So a BREAK is not a period of idleness between data, it's more like a giant start bit that lasts more than one character (usually tens to hundreds of characters).

Comment: you are absolutely right about the ancient protocols :P I'm sure it generates a break. Each set of data is preceded by logical low of at least 88us, so that should cover a few bytes of data with ease.

Comment: In that case, look into setting up the termios with `PARMRK` on and `IGNBRK`, `IGNPAR` and `BRKINT` off.  This will make a BREAK appear in the data stream as the three characters 0xff 0x00 0x00.  The first two mark it as a parity or framing error (you can't tell which) and 0x00 means it's a break (or a byte that's all zeros with a parity error, can't tell the difference either).  If your protocol is binary and 0xff 0x00 0x00 could be valid data then this has issues.  It's why I resorted to a custom line discipline.

Comment: You can also use the `read()` size, `VMIN` and `VTIME` to get data back in chunks that end after a certain inter-character timeout.  That timeout is specified in deciseconds, much too large if you want to find 88 µs pauses.  And this only works if you can begin each read() before the next chunk ends.

Comment: Unfortunatly the data is in binary, and 0xff 0x00 0x00 is a sequence that pops up quite often to... I saw VTIME before, but also noticed the decisecond timout which makes it unusable.

I tried messuring the time between each packet using blocking io on the serial port, but that only caught 1/50 of the packets i'm expecting, so no good solution there either